# Plot ECDF without loading all data in memory

Tags: python, matplotlib, memory, plot, ecdf

I need to plot the [ECDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) of some data.  I found out I could do it with

```
ecdf = sm.distributions.ECDF(sample) 
x = np.linspace(min(sample), max(sample))
y = ecdf(x)
plt.step(x, y)
```

using the `matplotlib` and `statsmodels` Python packages.

My problem is that the variable `sample` consists of around 1 GB of data, which I can't load into memory all at once.

How can I plot the ECDF while loading data in smaller slices?

Comment: How many data points are there?  Do you know that number exactly when you start?

Comment: Yes, I also know the minimum and the maximum value

Comment: But what is the (typical) input size?  And are the data sorted at all?

Comment: I have several dataframes saved on the filesystem with `pickle`.

All dataframes have the same structure and the `sample` is the concatenation of a specific column of these dataframes.


Suppose all dataframes have structure:

| uselessVariable1 | **VariableofInterest** | uselessVariable2 | etc. |

I need to compute the ECDF of the **VariableofInterest** across all dataframes.

Comment: @DavisHerring no sorting at all

Comment: Do you have 1G of data, or a 1G file? My real question is: would it work to read in your data piecewise and store in an array only the data you actually need for the ecdf?

Comment: I have 1G of data.

I've already tried to store the data I need into  an array but Python interpreter threw a MemoryError

Comment: Could using a [dask array](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array.html) help you store the data you need as you go? I am not familiar with ECDF, but i have had success using dask for things that won't fit into memory all at once.